# Jquery code not affecting my elements in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am making a woocommerce site that sells cabinet doors. An option that my company is providing to customers is the ability to add custom pre-drilled holes to the cabinet doors. However, they don't want the customer to see all the custom options if they haven't selected the "Boring" checkbox. So I tried to make a jQuery file to hide and show the form elements depending on the checkbox being checked. Although I believe I properly enqueued the file into my site, it doesn't seem to be affecting the elements and the console is not showing any errors. I am using a WooCommerce Product Add-on plugin which allows the checkbox to add to the total price of the product without affecting the price/sq. ft. of the product.

Here is the HTML code for the elements

```
<div class="required-product-addon product-addon product-addon-boring">

    <h3 class="addon-name">Boring <abbr class="required" title="Required field">*</abbr></h3>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-276-boring-0-0">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="addon addon-checkbox"  name="addon-276-boring-0[]" data-raw-price="7.50" data-price="7.5" value="yes"  /> Yes (<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>7.50</span>)</label>
</p></div>

<!--This is what I want to be hidden-->

<div class="product-addon product-addon-unit">

    <h3 class="addon-name">Unit </h3>

    <div class="addon-description"><p>Specify units for boring specs</p>

</div>
```

Here is the jQuery file I made to hide or show the elements when "addon-checkbox" is selected.

```
(function ($) {

$(".product-addon-unit").hide();
$(".addon-checkbox").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".product-addon-unit").show();
    } else {
        $(".product-addon-unit").hide();
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Here is how I enqueued the script.

```
function add_checkboxjquery() {
  wp_register_script('checkboxjquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/checkboxjquery.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);    
  wp_enqueue_script('checkboxjquery');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_checkboxjquery');
```

This doesn't seem to do anything and no errors appear. I can't seem to figure out what the next step is. The jQuery code does work fine when put in the console which puzzles me even more. Here is a link to a product page of the site for reference. Thank you in advance. http://mykitchencabinetdoors.com/product/sh1000/

Comment: Does it work if you go for `if ($(this).prop('checked'))` ?

Comment: Code shown works fine when you run it in console on that page. Actual code you you are using in the page is different though